# Web Based Monitoring App for Simple Java Application

Tags: java, health-monitoring, jamon

I have created a small `java application(myapp.jar).` This is a `multi threaded` application and We are going to run it on multiple machines(Separate instance for each machine). Now I want to create a `remote interface` so I can start, stop, monitor this application from a remote machine (most probably using Web Console). By monitoring I mean

```
   1. Whether this application is running on that machine or not?
   2. If its not running that Web console should provide capabilities to Start it.
   3. If its running then
```

--Web console should provide capabilities to stop execution
   --System should tell me value of different parameter like how many threads are running, value of some local parameter of my execution.

In which technology I should design this monitoring application. If there is any open source available to do this then please let me know. I heard about [JAMon api](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net) but dont know how it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd want a server machine that had this web interface to manage all the clients.  The clients would talk to this server through a web service, say polling it every 10 minutes or something.  You could then turn off and on these clients and when they poll the server, they'd know whether to start/stop etc.

Rather than going for some framework to setup the communications like JMS, I'd just say a HTTP web service over REST/SOAP should work fine for the clients to poll the server.

There's a question though on what should the clients do if they can't send to the server, maybe some local in memory DB like Derby would make sense for them to collect the messages.